# Xamarin.Forms DependencyService Get() Method Returns Null in PCL

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have the latest Xamarin Alpha installed and can't get UWP and DependencyService working.

In the UWP project I have:

```
Forms.Init(e);

// For release version, doc said debug will do this itself
DependencyService.Register<SpecialInterface>();
IInterface1 iinterface1 = DependencyService.Get<IInterface1>();
```

This does find the interface pointer.

In a PCL I have:

```
IInterface1 iinterface1 = DependencyService.Get<IInterface1>();
```

In a view model contained in the PCL (after a button click) it fails returning a `null` value for the `Get<IInterface1>()` call on both UWP and Android.

Here is the implementation contained in the UWP project:

```
using PrismUnityApp2.UWP;
using SharedProject1;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SpecialInterface))]

namespace PrismUnityApp2.UWP
{
    public class SpecialInterface : IInterface1
    {
        public SpecialInterface() { }

        public int TestMethod(int i)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the Interface is defined in a Shared Project as follows:

```
namespace SharedProject1
{
    internal interface IInterface1
    {
        int TestMethod(int i);
    }
}
```

I have the sample "UsingDependencyService" working in Android, WinPhone fails because HyperV is off for Android.

What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

Using following packages/versions:

- Prism.Unity.Forms 6.2.0.pre4
- Prism.Forms 6.1.0.pre4
- Xamarin.Forms 2.2.0.45
- Unity 4.0.1
- Windows 10 UWP

  ```
  public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
  {
      if (parameters.ContainsKey("title"))
          Title = (string) parameters["title"] + " and Prism";

      IInterface1 iinterface1 = DependencyService.Get<IInterface1>();
      if (iinterface1 != null)
      {
          int value = iinterface1.TestMethod(1);
          Title += " ::: " + value;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Try making the interface public?

Comment: That would have been an easy fix but I replaced internal with public and it still fails.  I will be looking at it again today so I may find something

Comment: You shouldn't need the Register method call, the attribute should be enough. Can you post the code with the DependencyService.Get and the click handling?

Comment: There are 2 .get lines above, is that what you want?  Added the use of the value at the end above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DependencyService.Get<IInterface1>()` call is returning null in the PCL because it's looking for a different version of `IInterface1` which is actually being defined multiple times.

Because `IInterface1` is located in a Shared Project that's referenced by both the PCL project and the UWP & Android projects, it's basically the same as creating the interface separately in both the PCL and app projects with the same name and signature. The parent assembly is different however.

If you were to move `IInterface1` into your existing PCL or a separate PCL that is referenced by both the existing PCL and your app projects, `DependencyService` should be able to locate your platform specific implementation, `SpecialInterface`, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone referring to null outcome on Xamarin, iOS : **ImagePickerService**

**DependencyService.Get();**

What i missed to include was,

```
Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<Xamarin.Forms.ImagePicker.IImagePickerService, Xamarin.Forms.ImagePicker.iOS.ImagePickerService>();
```

on AppDelegate , FinishedLaunching method.

Reference : https://github.com/matheusneder/Xamarin.Forms.ImagePicker

Answer (score 0):

check your class property and set build action to Compile or Embedded Resource .
its Will be OK.